# How to map to interface type property with AutoMapper and Unity

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper, unity-container

We're working on a .Net Core 3.1 project.

We're using AutoMapper to transform DTOs to model objects.
+ Unity for dependency injection

DTO :

```
    public class EmployeeDto
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

Interfaces :

```
    public interface ICompany
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IEmployee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public ICompany Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Implementations :

```
    public class Company : ICompany
    {
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee : IEmployee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICompany Company { get; set; }
    }
```

What I'd like to do is :

```
CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
     .ForPath(d => d.Company.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName));
```

*Of course*, I got an error "Cannot create an instance of interface type ... ICompany"

Is there any way for AutoMapper to use Unity resolvers to create an instance of Company for ICompany type (as registered in Unity) ? If yes, how and which could be the most appropriate approach ?

Thanks for help (and forgive my english ^^ don't hesitate to tell me you don't understand).

PS :

I searched and tried various but I'm a bit lost ^^

Maybe we should not be in this situation...; all tips are welcome but thanks to keep in mind the *main* question :)

**UPDATE**

Following this [link](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/987e0e37e69714b830191561e6c39150568c93ed/src/UnitTests/Constructors.cs#L1124)

This is how we registered types :

```
        public void ConfigureContainer(IUnityContainer container)
        {
            // Could be used to register more types
            container.RegisterType<ICompany, Company>();
            container.RegisterType<IEmployee, Employee>();

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                // this doesn't work
                //cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => container.Resolve(type));

                // this works
                cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => new Employee() { Company = container.Resolve<ICompany>() });

                cfg.AddProfile(typeof(AppProfile));
            });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            container.RegisterInstance(typeof(IMapper), mapper);
        }
```

Profile :

```
CreateMap<ICompany, Company>()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator(); // <- this seems to have no effect
CreateMap<IEmployee, Employee>()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator(); // <- this seems to have no effect

CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
    .ConstructUsingServiceLocator()
    .ForPath(d => d.Company.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName));
```

Do you see a way to make this more generic ?

```
cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(t => new Employee() { Company = container.Resolve<ICompany>() });
```

"Strange thing" : if I replace `EmployeeDto.CompanyName` by a `EmployeeDto.CompanyDto` and define the mapping CompanyDto -> Company, it works.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/987e0e37e69714b830191561e6c39150568c93ed/src/UnitTests/Constructors.cs#L1124) or [this](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Mapping-inheritance.html#as).

Comment: Tried both but without success :/ ```CreateMap<ICompany, Company>()      .ConstructUsingServiceLocator();``` and ```CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>().ConstructUsingServiceLocator().ForPath(d => d.Company.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName));```

Comment: That's a passing test there. Copy it and see how it works. Or try the second solution.

Comment: I've updated my question. If you could take a look.

Comment: I'm sure people did this before. For other containers, check https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution (not a DI problem). May I have your opinion on this :
**CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Company, opt => opt.MapFrom(z => container.Resolve(typeof(ICompany))))
    .ForPath(d => d.Company.CompanyName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CompanyName));**
I found that AutoMapper ignore d.Company destination member because no mapping defined for it (and it didn't match a source member). So I suppose AutoMapper never call his contructor.
would you say it is a good solution? or option ?

Comment: That's a hack :) See also https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html. But really, if all this doesn't add up, do it by hand, write the code you understand. There is no shame in that.